# Azure Gateway X-Forwarded-For header Absent

Tags: azure, gateway

According to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works#modifications-to-the-request Azure Application Gateway add to request 4 headers: x-forwarded-for, x-forwarded-proto, x-forwarded-port, and x-original-host. But it doesn't work for our application. x-forwarded-for is absent, all other headers are presented. We are using application gateway with Standard tier(not Standard v2). Is it limitation of Standard tier?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I encountered a problem which looked exactly the same but it really was traefik at the next hop which dropped the x-forwarded-for